# How to set argument for powershell command

Tags: c#, powershell

I need to execute console command powershell script with parameter in C# code and catch the results.
Currently i have this code:

```
private void PowershellMethod(string userSID)
        {
            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy")
                  .AddParameter("ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass")
                  .AddParameter("Scope", "Process")
                  .AddParameter("Force")

                ps.AddScript(@"C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\HotelMode-PB\\HotelMode.ps1");

                Collection<PSObject> result = ps.Invoke();
                foreach (var outputObject in result)
                {
                    // outputObject contains the result of the powershell script
                    Debug.WriteLine(outputObject.ToString());

                }
            }
        }
```

My intention is execute this command:

> HotelMode.ps1 -UserSid "user-sid-number" [-debug]

How should I set it in attached code?

Comment: Use `AddParameter("UserSid",userSID).AddParameter("Debug")` after `AddScript()`

Comment: oops. I am wondering how exactly should it look in my case, could you write it please? I have lost a bit.

Comment: ps.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy")
                  .AddParameter("ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass")
                  .AddParameter("Scope", "Process")
                  .AddParameter("Force")

                  .AddStatement()
                  .AddCommand("xxx")
                  .AddScript(@"C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\HotelMode-PB\\HotelMode.ps1")
                  .AddParameter("UserSid", userSID)
                  .AddParameter("Debug");

Is this how you mean it?

Comment: @PetSerAl You should add an answer

Comment: who puts final answear, he will receive points from me :-)